# Time format of videojs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-format, video.js, time-format

I am using videojs in my react project. Currently the time of player looks like this 0:00/0:10 . I want a time format of HH:MM:SS:FF (00:00:00:00) where F is frame. I am not able to find any solution. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: What do the `0:00` and `0:10` represent in `0:00/0:10`?

Comment: find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470715/videojs-display-current-time-in-minutes-and-seconds-instead-of-microseconds/31470859 it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the format `0:00/0:10`, but you can use the following function to convert time (in seconds) to `HH:MM:SS:FF` format :

```
var convertTime = function (input, fps) {
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;};
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 24 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input * fps % fps))
    ].join(':');
}
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var convertTime = function (input, fps) {
    var pad = function(input) {return (input < 10) ? "0" + input : input;};
    fps = (typeof fps !== 'undefined' ?  fps : 24 );
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input * fps % fps))
    ].join(':');
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
    5.4416555 : convertTime(5.4416555),
    126.2344452 : convertTime(126.2344452),
    1156.1535548 : convertTime(1156.1535548),
    9178.1351559 : convertTime(9178.1351559),
    13555.3515135 : convertTime(13555.3515135)
}, null, '\t') +  '</pre>';
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xf26snv/10/).

Comment: @ApurvG - No problem. Thanks for the upvote, even though it was late ;-)